# CoreData: Filtering a FetchRequest results are nil

Tags: ios5, core-data

I am trying to filter a fetch request to CD and initially it worked but now it is returning an empty array. I've checked the entity (Provider) and the key name I am trying to filter by is correct (providerName). I've checked the SQLite DB and the record with a name that matches the providerName I am searching for is there. (See attached images below). Could someone review my code and see if I am doing something wrong? Thanks:

```
- (NSArray* ) filterItemsFromCoreData : (NSArray* ) filters { 

//create a managed object context
NSManagedObjectContext* context = [self managedObjectContext];

//create error container and fetch request
NSError* errMsg;
NSFetchRequest* fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

//get our filters from passed array
NSString* filterProviderName = [filters objectAtIndex:0];
NSString* filterProviderZip = [filters objectAtIndex:1];
NSString* filterProviderPhone = [filters objectAtIndex:2];

//create predicate
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"providerName == %@", filterProviderName];

//create entity description
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription
                               entityForName:@"Provider" inManagedObjectContext:context];

//add entity and predicate to fetch request
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

//get the objects
NSArray *fetchedObjects = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&errMsg];
NSLog(@"%@", fetchedObjects);
return fetchedObjects;
}
```

Entity Screen Capture
[image: Entity Screen Cap]

SQLite DB
[image: SQLite DB]

Comment: are you sure you are using the same managedObjectContext ?? you should pass managedObjectContext between view controllers instead of creating a new one ... please provide the code for [self managedObjectContext]

Comment: ahmad, thanks for replying. This is happening in the viewcontroller, the mod is created here, see my reply below for more details.

Comment: You should be creating your managedObjectContext in AppDelegate, and then doing one of these `if (self.managedObjectContext == nil) {
        self.managedObjectContext = [(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext];
    }` in viewDidLoad of any class you need to access it from.

Answer (score 0):

Change the format specifier `%@` in your predicate format to be enclosed by single quotes `'%@'`.

`NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"providerName == '%@'", filterProviderName];`

This should return results again.

Comment: this format is a valid one too    predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"providerName = %@", filterProviderName];

Comment: No dice. I'm still getting (). When I run the request on just the entity (without the NSPredicate) it works fine.